# Register custom workflow activity in Dynamics CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have built a **Custom Workflow Activity** in Visual Studio 2010 to use in Dynamics CRM 2013 On-Premises and I am trying to register the assembly containing the custom workflow using Plugin Registration Tool with configuration: **Sandbox** and **Database**. I have spent hours struggling with the following exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Exception retrieving custom activity info - Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'TrmIntergration.Workflow.BaseCodeActivity'. Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible.
Detail: <OrganizationServiceFault xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ErrorCode>-2147200995</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
  <Message>Exception retrieving custom activity info - Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'TrmIntergration.Workflow.BaseCodeActivity'. Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible.</Message>
  <Timestamp>2014-07-31T09:58:46.057735Z</Timestamp>
  <InnerFault>
    <ErrorCode>-2147200995</ErrorCode>
    <ErrorDetails xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
    <Message>Exception retrieving custom activity info - Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'TrmIntergration.Workflow.BaseCodeActivity'. Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible.</Message>
    <Timestamp>2014-07-31T09:58:46.057735Z</Timestamp>
    <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
    <TraceText i:nil="true" />
  </InnerFault>
  <TraceText i:nil="true" />
</OrganizationServiceFault>

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IOrganizationService.Create(Entity entity)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy.CreateCore(Entity entity)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Libraries.RegistrationHelper.RegisterPlugin(CrmOrganization org, CrmPlugin plugin)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.AssemblyRegistration.PluginRegistrationViewModel.btnregisterClick()
```

Here is the Activity code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Activities;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow;

namespace TrmIntergration.Workflow
{
    public sealed class BaseCodeActivity: CodeActivity
    {        
        [Output("Initiating User")]
        [ReferenceTarget("systemuser")]
        public OutArgument<EntityReference> InitiatingUserReference { get; set; }
        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
        {
            IWorkflowContext workflowContext = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
            InitiatingUserReference.Set(executionContext, new EntityReference("systemuser", workflowContext.InitiatingUserId));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please share your code as well.

Comment: @Guido Preite I tried remove 'sealed', but it doesn't work. 
I think whether it is because .Net framework versions on my PC and CRM server are mismatch.

Comment: your code does exactly the same thing of this workflow activity I wrote some months ago: http://www.crmanswers.net/2013/10/get-current-user-inside-workflow.html with CRM 2013 onpremise you will not have problem with .net framework, because 4.5 is supported

Comment: Thanks, still, I am having no clue to register the workflow. Besides, I have no problem registering plugins. I have 4 plugins up and running currently. Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this will help... http://woodsworkblog.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/should-you-be-using-a-net-4-5-plugin-or-custom-workflow-activity-in-mscrm-2011-online/

Comment: @Ollie Thanks for sharing. I will take a look at .Net frameworks on my PC and CRM server.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [blog](http://xrmdevel.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/crm-2011-plugin-registration-error.html). Looks like the same issue.

The reason is that some legacy external libraries don’t follow .NET 4.0 security rules. The solution it actually quite simple – revert back to .NET 2.0 security. Simply add the following attribute anywhere inside you’re code (after the using statements):

```
[assembly: System.Security.SecurityRules(System.Security.SecurityRuleSet.Level1)]
```

Comment: I have tried it, but it shows a different exception:

`<Message>Exception retrieving custom activity info - Attempt by security transparent method 'Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.ObjectModel.CustomActivityHelper.GetDotNet4ParametersInfo(System.Type, Boolean, Microsoft.Crm.Metadata.DynamicMetadataCache, System.Guid)' to access security critical type 'System.Activities.RequiredArgumentAttribute' failed.</Message>`


I have also tried:
`[assembly: System.Security.SecurityRules(System.Security.SecurityRuleSet.Level2, SkipVerificationInFullTrust = true)]`


But it gives the 'violated type' exception above.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include `system.servicemodel` namespace.